# What is the difference between the type of SYMBOL and string in dolphindb?

Tags: dolphindb

What is the difference between the type of SYMBOL and string in dolphindb?
As I known, the Symbol type is also a type of string. What is the advantage by using it?

Answer (score 0):

SYMBOL is a special string type. It is equivalent to the enumerated type. It is recommended to use the SYMBOL type if there are a lot duplicate values for a certain field in a table, and the total number of values in different strings does not exceed 2097152 (2 to the 21st power).

The advantage of using the SYMBOL type is that it occupies less disk space and the retrieval speed is faster.